# How do I make a discord bot that will automatically join a Discord voice call when it goes online?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I've been trying to figure this out. I don't want to have to use commands to get the bot to join a voice call. I just want it to do it by itself as soon as it goes online. Could someone help me with that? Just so you know I'm using python.

Here are some things I've tried:

```
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
   channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
   await channel.connect()

@client.command()
   async def leave(ctx):
await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```

This is a good method but it requires user input and for the user to already be in a voice call. I want the bot to just automatically join a voice call as soon as it goes online. No user input required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a function called `on_ready()` that you can use. Inside the function you can get the voice channel desired and tell the bot to join it.

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_channels(), id=<the channel id>)
    await channel.connect()
```

Pointed out by comments, this version also works

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = bot.get_channel(<the channel id>)
    await channel.connect()
```

Note I have not tested this, it just *should* work.

Comment: Ah sorry I edited it to use channel id, you should use the id's whenever possible

Comment: it keeps saying things like bot isn't defined or client isn't defined. I've tried to fix but i cant get it to work. it also says that id=channel isn't defined either and i cant figure out how to define that.

Comment: I think \@bot.event should be \@client.event based on the code you posted. You might also need to change client.get_all_channels() to self.client.get_all_channels() depending on the rest of your code.

Comment: @Superior125 id=channel, channel should be replaced with the actual id number of the channel

Comment: it does not like "self"

Comment: I've edited the answer with the self and client changes, just to keep it accurate then.

Comment: i tried replacing it and it didnt work. all it was doing was saying "invalid syntax"

Comment: it likes this one bot.get_all_channels()

Comment: however how do I go about getting id working

Comment: You should just need to replace the <the channel id> with the channels id. You can get that by right clicking the channel and selecting Copy ID

Comment: @Superior125 btw what did you name the variable that is assigned to commands.Bot() when initializing the bot. Was it client or bot?

Comment: Ah well nvm then, glad I could help :)

Comment: This should be simply `bot.get_channel(123)`

Comment: Could only get this working with `PyNaCl` installed. That is, if you haven't already - run `pip install PyNaCl`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `on_ready()` function, write:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
   channel = client.get_channel(<id>)
   await channel.connect()
```